# What Am I missing Here? (.NET, Razor,MVC)

Tags: c#, .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a partial ViewModel from my Main ViewModel
and i need to return Byte for dropdownlist status model with Dictionary method

```
public static class ListStatus
{
    public static Byte Rejected = 0;
    public static Byte Pending = 1;
    public static Byte Reviewed = 2;
    public static Byte Accepted = 3;
}
```

Partial ViewModel :

```
@model byte
@{
    Layout = null;
    CategoryBusiness Business   = new CategoryBusiness();
    object attr = this.ViewBag.attr ?? new { @class = "form-control" };
    RouteValueDictionary attrDictionary = (attr as RouteValueDictionary) ??    new RouteValueDictionary(attr);
    attrDictionary["class"] = "required form-control";

    Dictionary<int, string> statuses = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    statuses.Add(Category.ListStatus.Rejected, "Rejected");
    statuses.Add(Category.ListStatus.Pending, "Pending");
    statuses.Add(Category.ListStatus.Reviewed, "Reviewed");
    statuses.Add(Category.ListStatus.Accepted, "Accepted");

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label text-right" })
    <div class="col-sm-10 editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model, statuses.Select(x => new  SelectListItem
    {
        Text = x.Value,
        Value = x.Key.ToString(),
        Selected = Convert.ToByte(x.Value) == Model
    }))
    @if (ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(Html.NameForModel().ToString()) && ViewData.ModelState[Html.NameForModel().ToString()].Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        @Html.Raw(Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "error" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("span", "label"))
    }
</div>
</div>
```

I have an error in DropDownlistFor with Exception
"Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: ViewModel in MVC ? really ?

Comment: You're missing a question.

Comment: whats your problem exactly?

Comment: @JeremyWeir I have an error in DropDownlistFor with Exception "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @S.Serp I have an error in DropDownlistFor with Exception "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Why in the world are you not using and `enum` and the `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line has problem-

```
Selected = Convert.ToByte(x.Value) == Model
```

As per the dictionary x.Value is a string value. It's ok to be string but it's not convertible to a valid digit. That's why it can not be converted to Byte and FormatException is thrown.

To know more about Convert.ToByte you can go thru https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k(v=vs.110).aspx

The solution would be to change the code as following.

```
Selected = Convert.ToByte(x.Key) == Model
```

Comment: That is pointless - just delete that line of code. The `Selected` property is completely ignored when using the `DropDownListFor()` method

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `Selected = Convert.ToByte(x.Value) == Model` actually be `Selected = Convert.ToByte(x.Key.ToString()) == Model` ?

Comment: I dont know whats going on! But it actualy Works! Thanks!